# Does static members prevent the instance class from being GC'ed?

Tags: c#, .net, static, garbage-collection

*Static members are not regarding the instance but the type itself.*

But I was wondering :

If I have this class :

```
public class A
{
 ...
 public static int MyInt{get;set;}
 ...
}
```

I can create of course `new A()`

But my question is :

- Does the static member which is "stucked" to the type itself , prevents the instance from being GC'ed ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not necessarily. The static member belongs to the class itself, which CLR keeps as a `Type` object. If the static member was an object of type `A`, then the static member could keep that *particular* instance of `A` from being garbage collected.

```
public class Example
{
    // this particular instance of Example will not be collected
    private static readonly Example Default = new Example();

    public void Foo()
    {
         // this instance *can* be collected after Foo returns
         Example anotherInstance = new Example();
    }
}
```

This behavior is useful for certain classes which aren't necessarily singletons but do have a "default" behavior that is stateless. One example where I use this is the [`ParseTreeWalker.Default`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/Tree/ParseTreeWalker.cs) field in the C# runtime library for the ANTLR 4 project. If you need the default behavior, you can use that instance without creating new objects, but you also have the option of creating your own instances of a class extending `ParseTreeWalker` to add your own behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. This can be easily shown by overwriting the finalizer.

Comment: Up voted for suggesting a test case. Could maybe use a code example.